# How to use regex to dynamically find a value in a file in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a long string like this for example:

```
V:"production",PUBLIC_URL:"",WDS_SOCKET_HOST:void 0,WDS_SOCKET_PATH:void 0,WDS_SOCKET_PORT:void 0,FAST_REFRESH:!0,REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID:"9mn5duMPUeNW5AJfbZWQgs5ivtiuYvQymqsCrZAenEdW",REACT_APP_SOLANA_NETWORK:"mainnet-beta
```

and I need to get the value of `REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID` with regex, the value of it is always 44 characters long so that is a good thing I hope. Also the file/string im pulling it from is much much longer and the `REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID` appears multiple times but it doesnt change

Comment: What have you tried? Check out [how to ask if you want to be helped](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex for that, just use `index()` to get the location of `REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID`.

```
data = 'V:"production",PUBLIC_URL:"",WDS_SOCKET_HOST:void 0,WDS_SOCKET_PATH:void 0,WDS_SOCKET_PORT:void 0,FAST_REFRESH:!0,REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID:"9mn5duMPUeNW5AJfbZWQgs5ivtiuYvQymqsCrZAenEdW",REACT_APP_SOLANA_NETWORK:"mainnet-beta'

key = "REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID"
start = data.index(key) + len(key) + 2

print(data[start: start + 44])
# 9mn5duMPUeNW5AJfbZWQgs5ivtiuYvQymqsCrZAenEdW
```